# Browser-Compatible Bookmarking Service With 'Export By Tag/Folder' Support

Tags: bookmarks

Is there a bookmarking service that allows users to organize bookmarks into folders, groups, or tags, and **more importantly**, allow users to export bookmarks from an individual folder, group or tag?

**PS:** As should be very clear from my question, the exported file should be browser-compatible (Chrome or Firefox) so that I can simply import them into my browser at will.

*FYI, I've tried Delicious, Google Bookmarks, Diigo, and Kippt. Services like Evernote and Springpad are out of question, as all I need is a simple bookmarking service.*

Comment: Not really anything to meet your exact needs, you have tried most services out there, time to make your own!

Comment: I assume you want a piece of software, but for tags you could export all your bookmarks to HTML and then write a batch script to snag all those lines into another file. Not an answer... but an idea.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5380253/1054225 This might be all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in/tour/). While I have not used the service personally, I understand that it saves pages in HTML (with excellent formatting at that) and is capable of managing thousands of bookmarks, with good export functionality.

**(EDIT by OP)** I contacted Maciej Ceglowski, founder of Pinboard, and he told me that it's actually possible to export bookmarks of a specific tag, which is exactly what I want. Here's how it's done:

```
https://pinboard.in/export/format:html/t:TAG/
```

In the above URL, replace the word `TAG` with the `NAME` of your tag. $9.97 very well spent!

Comment: Just paid $9.97 to check it out, only to realize it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work out for you- I'd email the developer and explain that it wasn't what you were looking for: maciej@ceglowski.com. No reason to be out $10 if you're not going to use it.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I contacted Maciej for a refund and clearly explaining why. He contact me back saying that it's possible, and stated how. I edited your answer with the details, so once the edit is approved by the mods it should be visible -- and then, I'll gladly remove my downvote. :-) As for why I downvoted in the first place -- I think an answer should be posted only when one is sure. Otherwise it'd better be a comment. Thank you, I've found what I need.

Comment: Understandable- I'm still getting used to the conventions on the site. I'm glad you were able to find a solution, and thanks for the  bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done any research on Speed Dials before? There is a couple good ones that you can find on Google or Firefox extensions. [Papaly](https://www.papaly.com/) is a great speed dial service with user integration. Chrome extension [Speed Dial FVD](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/speed-dial-fvd-new-tab-pa/llaficoajjainaijghjlofdfmbjpebpa?hl=en) is also a extremely good extension if you're using chrome.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it myself, but Xmarks is another similar service.

Comment: Xmarks is NOT a bookmarking service... more like a bookmark-syncing service.